# React App in netlify blank on Iphone but working on desktop

Tags: ios, reactjs, iphone

I'm creating a little app to calculate morgages, its working on Desktop but on my Iphone 13 I just get a blank screen (both safari and chrome).

I've seen some similar problems but usually they just mention regex expressions not supported (So I've already removed the regex expressions I was using) and the supported browsers list, so ive added "last 2 versions" to it.

```
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      "last 2 versions",
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 2 chrome version",
      "last 2 firefox version",
      "last 2 safari version"
    ]
  }
```

the app can be seen in : https://amortizacoes.netlify.app/
and the code can be seen in: https://github.com/sergiosaint/Finance

any Idea of what is making it not work on Iphone? (both chrome and safari)

Comment: Works fine on my Iphone. I think it has more to do with your phone than your app but I might be wrong.

Comment: you are right, I'm a morrow I was trying the wrong url nettlifly.app doesnt give any error.. just shows a blank page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a typo netlifly.app shows a blank screen, no error.

My company laptop says that url has a virus... dont visit it, seems like someone is exploiting the possibility of a typo to deploy malware or similar...